# Is there a way to integrate the unix “man pages” into OSX's Dictionary app?

Tags: macos, dictionary, manpages, integration

I was thinking it would be cool to be able to look things up in the man pages the same way one looks up words with the "Dictionary" app. Is there a way to add the man pages that OSX supplies into the Dictionary app so when you right click on a "word" (or in this case, a unix function/keyword/etc.), and click "Look Up in Dictionary", it can search for the word in the man pages too and integrate the search results into the Dictionary window? So when the window pops up, the tabs across the top would be "All", "Dictionary", "Thesaurus", "Apple", "Wikipedia", "Man Pages". Or is this too wishful of thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [The first Google result for "man pages dictionary plugin mac"](http://mosx.tumblr.com/post/7696350896/man-pages-plugin-for-dictionary-app)

[image]

There seems to be a lot of formatting issues though, for example it doesn't wrap text properly, so some pages have huge horizontal scroll bars. And you can't show man pages for manually installed commands like `brew`.

Comment: WOW i just forgot to use the google keyword "plugin".  awesome.  thanks!